# Getting error while download source code using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to download source code from a webpage. Here is my code:

```
var urlcli = new WebClient();
string sourcecode = urlcli.DownloadString(urltxt.Text.Trim());
```

In most cases, this code is working fine; but for some urls I'm getting the following error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Why don't you try something more on the lines of the example at the end of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx ; I mean, you probably need some closes(), or maybe disposals somewhere.

Comment: @JohnTortugo nothing is working for me. I'm getting same error usng htmlagilitypack

Comment: Possibly user agent and/or accept-language http headers missing.

Comment: @UweKeim Tried but not working

Comment: Any exception? You should be able to see the reason of the disconnection. Timeout?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't disposing the `WebClient` object. This may mean there are several `WebClient` objects that still exist after your program terminates and are holding open connections.

The fix would be to wrap it in a `using` statement:

```
string sourcecode;
using (var urlcli = new WebClient())
{
    sourcecode = urlcli.DownloadString(urltxt.Text.Trim());
}
```

In general, objects that implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) should call `Dispose()` or be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to be an answer for the question asked (even if it is poorly asked). Is it an answer?
Also "Any objects that implement `IDisposable` need to call `Dispose()` or be wrapped in a using statement" is an overgeneralization that tends to riddle the code  with unnecessary `try finally`. "need" is a pretty strong word. When exactly will you call `Dispose()` on `HttpClient`?

Comment: @LewsTherin sorry, but getting same problem "Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection..."

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Anything that implements IDisposable should implement dispose or use a using. If you do not, your application WILL leak handles to objects and could cause the application to crash as the OS only allows an application to have so many handles. Garbage collection does not free these up.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean first of all, garbage collection does nothing, that's true. The thread that consumes finalization queue does, it calls finalizers which in turn free unmanaged handles (if they are written correctly). That's why you probably (until your code is broken) won't leak anything if you remove all `using` aliases from your code. Secondly, for example, open documentation for `HttpClient` (or any post on SO about it and calling Dispose(), or use dotPeek to see the sources).

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Nothing bad will happen if you're not disposing `HttpClient`, if you create it locally for each request and call `Dispose()` afterwards, you'll probably have some issues. You should implement `IDisposable` to 1) free handles in a determined way and 2) to skip the pricey finalization.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov From [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects): "When you finish using an object that implements IDisposable, you should call the object's IDisposable.Dispose implementation." Now that being said, as with **anything** in programming, this is not a steadfast "do this in all situations" rule. However, in general it is a good idea to call `Dispose()` for classes that implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov As for this "not being an answer", the thought behind this answer was that maybe since OP didn't call `Dispose()` that there were a bunch of `WebClient` objects still holding a connection open. The OP has since confirmed that this did not fix his/her issue. I've left the answer up so that others who read this question do not attempt to give the same advice.

Comment: In general, sure. My comment was about original phrasing which, as I can see, you improved.

Comment: Ok, I got your logic about hanging connections. It would be cool if you put it into the answer, so other people can see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov I updated my answer to address your concern.